# best practices for dealing with a large number of images in a web app

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

So the user clicks an image and it opens in a new page with description etc. Im only dealing with 12 images so its not a big deal, but what if I had 500 or 1000+ images? Thats a alot of extra pages to deal with. I would imagine that you wouldn't want 1000 extra pages to open up so Im curious about best practice solutions for a large number of images under these specific circumstances. And this is being done with asp.net if that makes any difference.

> The application should still function like the midterm that if one
>   clicks on the small image clip a new page should be opened with a
>   larger image displayed along with a full description.  Please remember
>   to include coffee information such as calories, and nutritional facts.
>   Let’s have a limit of at least 4 pastries, 4 teas, and 4 coffees.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? Web Forms, MVC, etc.? You need to use some sort of URL or query string parameter to pass an ID of the image to a "coffee details" page. You would only have one coffee details page that reads the coffee ID from the URL, retrieves that coffee's details, and loads them on the page. So it's only one page that dynamically displays the appropriate details.

Comment: Web Forms and thank you very much. That answered my question.

Comment: That wasn't a fit question for SO though.